If the boundary of a set is a $C^1$ manifold must its epsilon neighborhood also have a boundary of $C^1$ manifold?
Let $K\subset\mathcal{R}^n$ be compact and suppose it has a $C^1$ boundary, then I think the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $K$ must have some form of smoothness for its boundary for any $\epsilon >0$. What kind of smoothness can I claim? I don't think I can claim it is $C^1$ because consider two disjoint circles put side by side some distance apart, their $\epsilon$ neighborhood will have a kink on its boundary making it not $C^1$?
I have minimal knowledge of differential geometry so please go easy on me. I think I can claim $C^1$ if $K$ is connected. But if $K$ is not connected, I'm not sure what kind of smoothness I can claim. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Connectedness is not an issue (provided $\epsilon$ is suitably small). Just work with components. How might you try to prove this statement? Can you locally parametrize the boundary of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood?

@TedShifrin Thank you so much. I see what you are saying. Since I can contain each connected component in disjoint $\epsilon$ neighborhood (provided $\epsilon$ is small enough), I can just focus on one connected component. But I need it to work for any $\epsilon >0$. So I think I have a counter example for that case so I will refine my question.

Oh, it's definitely false if you try to make it work for large $\epsilon$, even with one component.

@TedShifrin For my education, could you provide me an example where it fails to be $C^1$ with one component? Thank you so much.

Well, even with a circle of radius $R$, you run into trouble (on the inside) when $\epsilon=R$. But more interesting things happen with focal points. Try a parabola, for example.

@TedShifrin Wow, of course. Thank you so much. I was only thinking of $K$ with non-empty interior. If I can't claim $C^1$, is there, any smoothness property I can claim?

No, there is only good control for small $\epsilon$. Play with pacman shapes, too.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much. I learned a lot and you gave me much to think about.

If you want to go down a big rabbit hole, read about sets of positive reach (originally defined by H. Federer in his work in geometric measure theory). This all makes sense with more relaxed notions of smoothness.

I gotta say that the nicest examples of sets with positive reach are boundaries of convex sets. Convex sets have much nicer regularity properties than sets of positive reach, so you can avoid geometric measure theory. But you can do a lot with convex sets without making any additional regularity assumptions.
